# Writing a helper that produces bound results?

Tags: ember.js, mustache

I have a date/time formatting helper but what it produces does not update when the underlying property changes.  This is not a surprise, but does anyone know how to produce bindings in helpers?

I invoke the helper like this...

```
{{timestamp created_at}}
```

...and here is the helper itself:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('timestamp', function(context, options) {
  var formatter        = options.hash['format'] ? options.hash['format'] : 'hh:mm a MM-DD-YYYY';
  var original_date    = Ember.getPath(this, context); // same as this.get(context) ?
  var parsed_date      = moment(original_date);
  var formatted_date   = parsed_date.format(formatter);

  return new Handlebars.SafeString("<time datetime=" + original_date +">" + formatted_date + "</time>");
});
```

Comment: A tiny update to this one just to mention that bound helper has just been commited to master.
see https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/46469831e7fe22d43b5dcfdf7ff60bd7000aa9de

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is now possible to create bound Handlebars helpers using a public Ember API.

```
Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('timestamp', function(date, options) {
  var formatter        = options.hash['format'] ? options.hash['format'] : 'hh:mm a MM-DD-YYYY';
  var parsed_date      = moment(date);
  var formatted_date   = parsed_date.format(formatter);

  return new Handlebars.SafeString("<time datetime=" + date +">" + formatted_date + "</time>");
});
```

The parameter passed to the helper will have already been resolved, and the helper will be called again whenever the path changes.

Comment: That is hugely cool! It adds an extra layer of flexibility. I do personally have "localisation" in mind. A helper "t" to translate a string that will update automatically when the STRINGS array change. Awesome. Will give that a try.

Comment: Note that is cannot be used with a block helper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005111/custom-handlebars-helper-parameter-is-not-resolved

Comment: If you need a block helper, chances are you should be using a component.

Comment: I'd like the options hash to support bound values as well. Is that crazy? My desired use case: `{{format-time "%F %X" time=thing.time}}`

Answer (score 10):

It is unfortunately more complex than I'd like to create a custom helper with bound content. Here's an example that Peter Wagenet wrote: https://gist.github.com/1563710

I'll be lobbying for this to become easier.

Comment: Crap that's even more complex than I thought it would be... I'd be interested to see how that becomes simpler.

Comment: Agreed. There should definitely be some sugar here.

Comment: Note that the latest version of Ember breaks this because Ember.Metamorph has been renamed Ember._Metamorph. Here's an updated gist: https://gist.github.com/2588802

Comment: Sorry but this hasn't been working at all on my side... We finally been using more sophisticated computed properties. But in the date formatting case, it's not appropriate. Any progress by anybody?

Comment: @nembleton See my answer. Bound helpers are now an Ember feature.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to this particular question, but I also created helpers in views and wanted the values to update when data in the Ember.js view changed. The way I solved this problem was to write an observer on the values I wanted changed and used jQuery to update the specific value.

For example (in Coffeescript):

```
...

attrObserver: Ember.observer(() ->
  $("#attrId").text(this.get("attr"))

...
```