# How do you make a Handlebars helper that is aware of Ember bindings?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

When I try to pass an Ember binding or computed property to a custom Handlebars helper, the helper receives the string instead of the value. How do I get the value into the helper?

The template:

```
{{my_helper my.binding}}
```

The helper receives "my.binding" instead of the corresponding value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few days ago a [push on the master](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/1274) solved the problem : 
use Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper.

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('myHelper', 
    function(myBinding, options) {
        return myDealWith(myBinding);
    }
);
```

Comment: You cannot do with with block objects.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use *Ember.getPath* to get the value in helper method.
See the docs http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_writing-custom-helpers

Comment: Is there a reason I should use `Ember.getPath(this, property)` over `this.getPath(property)`?

Comment: You'd want to use `Ember.getPath` if you ever expect `this` to not be an `Ember.Object`.

Comment: ... which is to say, most of the time you can (and should) be using `this.getPath`.

Comment: Also note that this won't *bind* the attribute, only *get* it. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837958/writing-a-helper-that-produces-bound-results.