# how do you make a handlebars block helper that is aware of ember bindings

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

This is similar to the question asked in this post:[How do you make a Handlebars helper that is aware of Ember bindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856216/how-do-you-make-a-handlebars-helper-that-is-aware-of-ember-bindings)

I want my customized Handlebars block helper to be aware of Ember bindings:

```
{{#myHelper my.binding}}
    show something here
{{/myHelper}}
```

But the helper receives `my.binding` as string instead of the value. How do I pass the value into the helper?

Comment: Use a component instead.

Comment: What version of Ember?

Comment: @DanielKmak Ember version is 1.8.1

Comment: @ChristopherMilne If the helper is really simple in logic, writting a component looks overkill?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted your helper code, nor the versions you're using, so it's difficult to say what could be wrong. I would still refer to the documentation: http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/templates/writing-helpers/.